# Android: AppCompatTextView custom style

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm going to set default style for **AppCompatTextView** through whole application including `android:textColor`, `android:maxLines`, and `android:inputType`.

I found that I can set default style for **AppCompatEditText** by following codes.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--EditText Style-->
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/My_EditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="My_EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">text</item>
    ...
</style>
```

So what would be the item name for `AppCompatTextView` like `"editTextStyle"` here? I tried with `"textViewStyle"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/My_EditTextStyle</item>
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/My_EditTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/My_TextViewStyle</item>
        <item name="textViewStyle">@style/My_TextViewStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="My_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">text</item>
        ...
    </style>    

    <style name="My_TextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">text</item>
        ...
    </style>
```

Comment: I didn't mean EditText but TextView

Comment: Could you remove unnecessary sentences except "android:textViewStyle"?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `<style name="My_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">`
With `<style name="My_textView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">`

REFERENCE IT.

Comment: I didn't mean EditText but TextView